# Can we read .properties file inside xml?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, properties

I have a .properties file that contains the values. I am trying to set one of the value to a field in xml file.
For example session-expiry is set to 300 seconds in property file.
So i need to set the same value in the xml file.

```
<max-idle-seconds>300</max-idle-seconds>
```

This 300 should be takem from the .properties file.
Can anyone help?

Comment: ... if I understand correctly you just have two xml files that you want to merge in some way? And also what programing language are you planning to use for that anyways?

Comment: one is xml and another one is .properties file. I am going to do it in java

Comment: add the java tag it'll help you get a response

Comment: You'll need to either preprocess or postprocess the xml file. There is no way for it to insert .properties into xml magically.

Comment: what about this tag <property file = "someName.properties">
Will it load the file?

Comment: If you need to see the values of .properties inside the xml file,then while taking the build of the application itself, you have to write some script like ant,perl,ruby or shell script to replace the values. Say if you are using some framework like Spring, check for `property-placeholder` which would read the property file on startup and while creating the beans(objects) from xml configuration file (having placeholders to be replaced from a property file) , spring would create the objects based on this  property file. https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Add your XML below the code.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:your_property_filename.properties"  ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Or you can write:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:your_property_filename.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```